# An Evolution Equation with the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator is  given by $Lf(x)=\Delta f(x) - x\cdot\nabla f(x)$. My questions pertain to the PDE given by

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= L f(x).$$

(1) Is there a name for this differential equation ?

(2) Did Ornstein and Uhlenbeck use this equation in their research ?  If so, I am interested in at least one source text so that I may read more about this equation.

Answers to these questions can help to provide a context for research related to this equation.